# How to escape HTML in node.js EJS view?

Tags: html, node.js, ejs

I want to escape the html in bloglist[i].Text field. How to do that with EJS?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title><%= title %></title>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='/stylesheets/style.css' />
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1><%= title %></h1>
    <p>Welcome to <%= title %></p>
    <% for(var i=0; i < bloglist.length; i++) { %>
       <h3> <%= bloglist[i].Title %></h3>
       <div>
          <%= bloglist[i].Text %>
       </div>
    <% } %>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 118, accepted):

You are escaping the value correctly by using:

```
<%= bloglist[i].Text %>
```

If you want to allow HTML to be rendered, then you want an "unescaped" value.  To do that use the following:

```
<%- bloglist[i].Text %>
```

All I did was replace the equal (=) with a dash (-).

Reference: https://github.com/visionmedia/ejs/tree/0.8.3#features

Comment: and if I want escaped all HTML except <em> or <br> for exemple?

Comment: That's currently not possible. You may have to manually do the encoding.