# When I JSON.stringify(object) I get a crazy string as a value

Tags: javascript, json, express, ejs

When I send an object with an array of objects in it from my express route to my client, I get an [Object object] and then when I try to stringify it, I get this crazy string with this console message

```
var messages = "<%=(JSON.stringify(messages))%>"
console.log(messages)
```

Which prints this out to the console ...

```
{&#34;messages&#34;:[{&#34;content&#34;:&#34;cool mane&#34;,&#34;creator&#34;:&#34;joe&#34;},{&#34;content&#34;:&#34;test 4&#34;,&#34;creator&#34;:&#34;joe&#34;},{&#34;content&#34;:&#34; ewgdqf&#34;,&#34;creator&#34;:&#34;joe&#34;},
```

It should be something so I can iterate through it by doing
messages[0].content but I'm getting this crazy string that won't let me do anything with it...

If I try to loop through it, it just prints out each character by itself.

Comment: Seems like `<%= ... %>` is HTML encoding the output. Template engines often provide a way to output stuff without encoding it. Once you fixed that, you need to `JSON.parse` the string as well. Still wondering whether there is a better way to pass the object to the client.

Comment: i don't think there's any other way to send data to the client, but JSON.parse gives me an error everytime I try to use it even after I stringify it

Comment: @T.J.Crowder that's just a typo from trying 100 different things I accidently kept them when I went back to my original code

Comment: As you said, you need to fix the output before you can use `JSON.parse`. You have to use the non-encoding version of `<%= ... %>`, whatever that is. Which template engine are you using?

Comment: According to http://stackoverflow.com/a/16184093/218196, you have to use `<%-`. So your code should be: `var messages = JSON.parse('<%-JSON.stringify(messages)%>');`. Give that a try...

Comment: just pointing out that `console.dir()` is sometimes useful on complex objects

Comment: @FelixKling I've tried that but I keep getting the Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier error when I use the - instead of =

Comment: Uh, I'm stupid. Just do `var messages = <%-JSON.stringify(messages)%>;`.

Comment: @FelixKling the single quotes were my problem, it's working now and the format is actually readable no more &#34 

But now it's still treating it like a giant string. I can't access the message array inside of it by doing messages.messages

Comment: @FelixKling - NO not stupid, :) we all have those "can't see the obvious" moments.  I let at my former co-worker Max look at mine while I explain to him what it does.  He passed away several years ago but still helps me out often.

Comment: @FelixKling okay after doing messages = JSON.parse(messages) everything is working perfectly. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss I think felix was actually right.. I just messed up the syntax with using " instead of '

Comment: Yeah, that will work, but only until your data contains a `'` somewhere ;) See my comment and answer.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

When using `<%= ... %>`, EJS will encode / escape any output. That's why the `"` in the JSON are encoded as `&#34;`. [According to this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16184093/218196), you can prevent escaping by using `<%- ... %>` instead.

There is also no need to put the output inside a string literal. It's actually bad since you can get problems with nested quotes. Just let it output directly into the JS code:

```
var messages = <%-JSON.stringify(messages)%>;
```

Comment: Yep this is the answer.

Comment: Great ! Thank you

Comment: When i console the variable after using `<%- .... %>` am getting Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier error. Why am i getting this error?

Comment: @Ben: No idea. Did you look at the code that the browser sees?

Answer (score -1):

Try to change this :

```
var messages = "<%=(JSON.stringify(messages))%>"
console.log(messages)
```

With this :

```
var messages = JSON.stringify("<%=messages%>");
console.log(messages)
```

Comment: What's the point of calling `JSON.stringify` on a **string**? Also, what will be the result / output of `<%=messages%>`?

Comment: @FelixKling lol... my question would be, what is the output of `messages`?

Comment: It consoled out "[object Object]" if I just console out without stringifying it, it consoles out [object Object]

Comment: @evolutionxbox the output of messages is [object Object]