# Iframe content is a text not html code

Tags: javascript, iframe, ejs

I have a problem with iframe. I added HTML code (string - I get that code from DB) in the `<body>` of iframe but I can't see that code as HTML, its just a string.

```
document.getElementById("iframe_with_content").ready(function() {
        (document.getElementById("iframe_with_content").contentWindow.document).write("<%= post.text %>");
        (document.getElementById("iframe_with_content").contentWindow.document).close();
});
```

[image: bug]

Answer (score 2):

Include jQuery to your page, and

```
var data = $('<textarea />').html("<%= post.text %>").text();
document.getElementById("iframe_with_content").ready(function() {
        (document.getElementById("iframe_with_content").contentWindow.document).write(data);
        (document.getElementById("iframe_with_content").contentWindow.document).close();
});
```

Explanation: your data provided by `<%= post.text %>` was actually html-entity-encoded. So actually you've got something like `sadasds&lt;i&gt;dasd...`.

Comment: Thank you so much! Tried a lot of things but only this one worked for me

Answer (score 0):

This can occur because of html escaping done by ejs try and check to see whether this works:

```
<%- post.text %>
```

Refer : [How to escape HTML in node.js EJS view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16183748/how-to-escape-html-in-node-js-ejs-view)

WARNING: Be careful using these functions please check XSS attacks