# How to display html from a mongodb database in nodejs

Tags: node.js, database

I'm stuck with trying to figure out how to display html tags inside of a mongodb table. Everytime I view the data through the browser, it shows the text of the html. Example:

I have this in a mongodb database table:

**Test**
It should display as this when viewed on a webpage: Test

But instead, it displays **Test**

Comment: How are you getting the HTML from the database to the browser? Are you using a templating engine, just sending it as a string, etc...?

Comment: yes i am using ejs..............

Answer (score 1):

### Your Issue

I haven't used [EJS](http://ejs.co/) before but I'm assuming its an issue with how you're inserting the HTML strings from the database into your EJS templates.

In most templating engines, simply inserting a string containing HTML markup will result in the engine *escaping* the HTML instead of rendering it.

**EXAMPLE**
INPUT > `<div class='box'> <p class='item'>Hello World</p></div>`
OUTPUT > `&lt;div class='box'&gt; &lt;p class='item'&gt;Hello World&lt;/p&gt;&lt;/div&gt;`

This is normal and there are many reasons for it, one of which is security.

### Solution

If it is, in fact, an issue with EJS escaping the HTML, you must instruct EJS to not escape it. I've never used EJS before but a quick google search for `EJS escape html` brought up this result [How to escape HTML in node.js EJS view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16183748/how-to-escape-html-in-node-js-ejs-view)

### For future reference

While EJS will escape your HTML by default stack overflow does not. When you inserted `<strong>` in your question, stack overflow rendered it as HTML.

To get StackOverflow (and most other markdown readers) to render any HTML markup literally like I've done above, wrap the HTML in *graves* `.

Also, try to provide more information in your questions. The more information, the easier it is to deduce the likely source of the problem.