# How to render markdown in ejs page

Tags: javascript, html, express, ejs, blogs

i want to create small blog using express , ejs and markdown but when i tried to load markdown on page i saw this: 
[image]

my code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pl">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Blog</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <%=title%> <%=body%>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to escape HTML in node.js EJS view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16183748/how-to-escape-html-in-node-js-ejs-view)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is simple you have to change your tags to <%- yourVar%>

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pl">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Blog</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <%-title%> <%-body%>
  </body>
</html>
```